# How to use update and paintEvent in a QWidget in pyside?

Tags: python, pyside

Being new to `pyside` I am still having trouble understanding some GUI concepts, even aware of decent [documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.paintEvent).

I have a widget, dervied from `QWidget`, which I want to draw inside a function `paintEvent`, which is the function called to paint the widget (as far as I understood the documentation). Also, the method `update` should be used to update the widget, which calls the method `paintEvent` (as far as I understood the documentation).

In the following code skeleton I give a short overview of my code which should do two things: 
 - when initialized the widget should be drawn
 - if required, the widget should be redrawn by a call to `update` inside the derived class

```
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.update() # update the widget for the first time

    def paintEvent(self, x):

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 970, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Window")
        ...
        self.table_model = MyTableModel(...)
        self.view =  QTableView()
        ...
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def do_something(self):
        ....
        self.update()
```

When running the code the widget is drawn as expected. But once the call to `update` is made inside `do_something` nothing happens, the widget is NOT redrawn! I also tried to use the method `repaint` instead, but the widget is still not redrawn.

How to fix the code to ensure the widget is redrawn from scratch by calling `paintEvent`?

Comment: Why are you building the GUI inside the `paintEvent`?! Why do you need to override the `paintEvent`? Your widgets will manage to show up and redraw themselves automatically.

Comment: @Bartosz: Maybe I am doing the thing completely wrong, but as I am quite new to pyside I still do not have the overview. Would it be better to create the widget as part of a other widget? Or panel? Or MainWindow? The thing is, that the data shown by the code example is on the main widget/window/panel/whatever of my application. If I would make this widget as part of the main window, will a widget.update() work then?

Comment: In most cases shouldn't have a need to call `widget.update()`. Typically you just add a layout to your widget (`setLayout` in initialization method, **not** in `paintEvent`) and then add other sub widgets to this layout. OS/Qt/pyside take care of redrawing them appropriately.

Comment: But how does OS/Qt/pyside know when to redraw the widget? How does it know that the content of a database has changed so it requires a redraw? And what is the appropriate method to define all the drawing stuff? Should I still put them into paintEvent? Or some other method?

Comment: When you change the text of a text box for example, it will know it needs to refresh itself. You don't need to define the drawing stuff - the widgets now how to draw themselves. Either you don't understand how most GUI libraries work in general and I'd advise you to study some simple examples first, or you are trying to achieve something more advanced that indeed needs `paintEvent` - but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: I probably do not understand the GUI concept. I will ask a more specific question.

Comment: first research, then ask ;)

Comment: I have researched before I asked my question. I have looked into the documentation, but it seems to work differently. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229657/how-to-organize-pyside-objects-to-show-a-table-that-might-get-updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55652/discussion-between-alex-and-bartoszkp).